# CSS3 Transition not working in Firefox

Tags: css, css-transitions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS3 transition of background-image for Firefox not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354742/css3-transition-of-background-image-for-firefox-not-working)

first post here. I've researched and have seemingly been close to finding the answer, but maybe I'm just frustrated.

I can't get my CSS3 transition of ease-in-out of a background image to work in FF, but it works in Chrome.

Here's my code via jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hWnf4/

HTML:

```
<a href="http://example.com" title="" id="logo">
<span id="logoimg"></span></a>​
```

CSS:

```
#logo {display:inline-block; padding-top:22px; text-decoration:none;font-family:'YanoneKaffeesatzRegular',"Helvetica", Arial, sans-serif;font-size:3em;margin-bottom:18px;}
#logo:link, #logo:visited {color:#fff;}
#logo:hover, #logo:active {color:#ccc;}
#logoimg {display:inline-block; width:405px; height:220px; background:url('http://www.webdesign-guru.co.uk/icon/wp-content/uploads/black-round-glassy.gif') no-repeat; transition: background .25s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: background .25s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;}
#logoimg:hover {background:url('http://www.webdesign-guru.co.uk/icon/wp-content/uploads/green-round-glassy-button.gif') no-repeat;}​
```

Comment: It works in FF. Which version of FF are you using?

Comment: Oh, I guess I passed that question. Thanks. That sucks that it's not supported yet. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you.

http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/#background-image