# Transition not working on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, transition

I'm running this code, by hovering over the image another one appears, and it has a transition code. Weirdly, it doesn't work on FireFox, but works on Opera and Google Chrome. I hoped you could help me, this is my first post.

**CSS**:

```
.class1 {
    visibility: visible
}

.class2 {
    background: url(image2); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    -webkit-transition:all .9s ease; 
    -moz-transition:all .9s ease; 
    -o-transition:all .9s ease; height: 173px
}

.class1:hover .class2 {
    background: url(image1); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    -webkit-transition:all .7s ease; 
    -moz-transition:all .7s ease; 
    -o-transition:all .7s ease; height: 173px
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="class1" style="width: 280px; float:center">
    <p style="float:center" class="class2">
    </p>
</div>
```

Doesn't seem to work on Firefox. The image is there and the transition works, on Firefox it works weird, you hover over it and it has no transition, just straight changing image.

Comment: Can you put a demo on jsfiddle.net? Thanks.

Comment: There is also no such property as `float:center`

Comment: If I recall correctly, Mozilla Firefox no longer uses `-moz` prefix.

Comment: Here I did it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/fQeHL/3/

Comment: @user3617987 is right the effect is not the same even if you remove the prefix.

Comment: >float:center works in my forum, don't know why. BTW, [here is it](http://jsfiddle.net/X3GYY/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using css3 with vendor prefixes you need to add the actual css3 equivalent also, not just the prefixes, they were a stop gap while standards were being adopted.

The latest Firefox has adopted css3 as the standard (No prefixes and no support for them), but the prefixes still support older versions, so it is not wrong to use them but they are only a fall back.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
.class1 {visibility: visible}
.class2 {
    background: red; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    -webkit-transition:all .9s ease; 
    -moz-transition:all .9s ease; 
    -o-transition:all .9s ease; 
    transition:all .9s ease; 
    height: 173px}
.class1:hover .class2 {
    background:yellow; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    -webkit-transition:all .7s ease; 
    -moz-transition:all .7s ease; 
    -o-transition:all .7s ease; 
    transition:all .7s ease; 
    height: 173px
    }
</style>

<div class="class1" style="width: 280px; float:left;"><p style="float:center<class="class2">HJKHKSF</p></div>
```

I took the images out and used colours.

**No further comment: After a little research it appears firefox does not support transition animation on background-images**

Comment: I tried it here and it still does not have the same effect that you see in other browsers.

Comment: I get a fade in fade out from red to yellow in all browsers. What are you seeing? Check it here [jsfiddle css3 transition](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4qbT/)

Comment: Try it with an image like @user3617987 is trying to do. It does not work for some reason.

Comment: Found a [previous stackoverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354742/css3-transition-of-background-image-for-firefox-not-working). Looks like Firefox does not support transitions on background-image

Comment: Aw. Too bad. Thanks tho, for helping.

Comment: We all learn together, use javascript if you are desperate, probably a bit of a gimmicky effect ;)